# How to check GPRS Availability before sending Data through HttpConnection

Tags: java-me, nokia, midp, gprs, httpconnection

I am making one Java ME Application. Here I am using `HttpConnection` for making `Connection` with webservices. I send/Receive data using `HttpConnection`, `DataInputStream` & `DataOutputStream`. But My Problem is that How can I check that currently GPRS connection is available or not ?

I got, `System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.networkavailability");` API to check the Network's Availability. But I want to know how to check if GPRS is available or not ? Help Me Regarding this. ( I am using Nokia's E5 Phone for Development work ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A1F90B63-5F14-4829-BCA1-A23B925CF670.html), You can use the following property for getting the network access type of used active connection or a set default access point.

`String value = System.getProperty("com.nokia.network.access");`

Also you can read this article, [IAP Info API in Java™ ME.](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-660EC670-B7DB-4005-BF2D-411E5C0B3867_overview-1-9-1-8-6.html) It will helps you.

Comment: sorry ? what do you mean ? I am new to this site